# How can I exclude repeating elements within chunks of data in array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, dataframe

I have a file with following data array

```
7
1  2  3  120.12
4  5  8   70.25
6 11 12  111.20
2  6 10   90.39
3  2  1  120.12
10 6  2   90.39
11 2  3   87.12 
9
1  2  3  110.12
4  5  8   70.25
6 11 12  111.20
2  6 10   60.39
3  2  1  110.12
10 6  2   60.39
11 2  3   87.12
20 1  9  156.48
3  2 11   87.12 
...
```

File is consist of tens of datablocks. Each datablock has one top header line (number of data lines = size of datablock), and data section has 4 columns. These 4 columns are angles for 3 points. First three columns are point number or point index. And 4th column is the angle of 3 points. So, it is "ID1 ID2 ID3 angle". For example, "1  2  3  120.12" means angle of 1-2-3 (vertex is '2' in this case) is 120.12 degree.

Problem is, there are repeating elements. In first frame, there is 2 repeating pairs: 1 2 3 and 3 2 1, and 2 6 10 and 10 6 2. In second frame, there is 3 repeating item, 1 2 3 and 3 2 1, and 2 6 10 and 10 6 2, and 11 2  3 and 3  2 11. All of those pairs are same angle, but just opposite direction.

How can I exclude those repeating elements and leave only one for each datablocks? I wish the above example to become like this:

```
5
1  2  3  120.12
4  5  8   70.25
6 11 12  111.20
2  6 10   90.39
11 2  3   87.12 
6
1  2  3  110.12
4  5  8   70.25
6 11 12  111.20
2  6 10   60.39
11 2  3   87.12
20 1  9  156.48
...
```

I wish to get the distribution and normalPDF of angle per each datablocks and for all angles regardless of angles. But I'm not sure how can I exclude those repeating combinations.

There are slim chances of same angle 'luckily' occur with different combo, so I was trying to exclude repeating elements based on ID numbers, like ID1 ID2 ID3 repeats by ID3 ID2 ID1. But I couldn't find any proper logic for if-loop and for-loop or function...

Comment: Check whether you have identical elements in second column of each block, collect qualifying rows, sort them, and compare with `equal()`? (Honestly, this sounds like better done in Google Sheet)

Comment: Please provide the code you use to read in the data.

Comment: btw, if I were you, I would post an example where people can actually use your data. Right now, I can't copy your text output and convert it into an array Matlab without doing something extra. Even just encapsulate your individual blocks with `block=[ ... ]` is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have separated your blocks and one of the blocks is stored as a n-by-4 double array `block`.

What you need, is to sort the vertices in each row while keeping the 2nd one fixed. That can be achieved by using `sort` along the row dimension as follows

```
sort([block(:,1),block(:,3)],2);
```

The second input `2` specifies sorting all rows along column.

Next, you need to add back the 2nd vertices and pick out the unique vertex combinations.

```
unique([block(:,2),sort([block(:,1),block(:,3)],2)],'row');
```

`'row'` means pick out unique rows as a whole, instead of unique individual elements. You can add `'stable'` to preserve the existing order. But you didn't specify such a need in the question. So I'll keep it optional.

To get the original vertex order, we use the indices of the unique rows as follows. Here, you need to be sure that duplicate angles identified by valid vertex sequence have the same angle value. (Otherwise, you need to add `block(:,4)` to the above formula.)

```
[~, ind] = unique([block(:,2),sort([block(:,1),block(:,3)],2)],'row');
```

And your final answer is: (just the two lines below)

```
[~, ind] = unique([block(:,2),sort([block(:,1),block(:,3)],2)],'row');
block(ind,:),
ans =
    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000  120.1200
   11.0000    2.0000    3.0000   87.1200
    4.0000    5.0000    8.0000   70.2500
    2.0000    6.0000   10.0000   90.3900
    6.0000   11.0000   12.0000  111.2000
```

---

If someone could write a loop based answer with manual caching, I would be curious to see between the above and looping with manual caching, which one is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic job for [**`accumarray`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). As you didn't provide any code for loading the data, I just read it in with `readmatrix`. You may need to adapt the code, if you load it another way.

```
% given
DATA = readmatrix('data.txt','NumHeaderLines',0);      % load data
DATA(:,end) = [];                                      % remove last column, as only NaN

hl = any(isnan(DATA(:,2:end)),2);                      % identify header lines
subs = cumsum(hl);                                     % indices for accumarray

% unqiue rows of chunks of data
y = accumarray(subs(:), ...                            % indices of chunks
               1:numel(subs).', ...                    % numbering of rows
               [], ...                                 % not used
               @(x) { ...                              % anonymous function
               unique( ...                             % unique 'rows' of chunks
               [sort( DATA(x,1:3), 2) DATA(x,4)], ...  % first 3 columns sorted
               'rows', 'stable' ...                    % stable -> do not change order
               )});
y = cell2mat(y);                                       % tranfsform back to array
```

---

```
y =

    7.0000       NaN       NaN       NaN
    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000  120.1200
    4.0000    5.0000    8.0000   70.2500
    6.0000   11.0000   12.0000  111.2000
    2.0000    6.0000   10.0000   90.3900
    2.0000    3.0000   11.0000   87.1200
    9.0000       NaN       NaN       NaN
    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000  110.1200
    4.0000    5.0000    8.0000   70.2500
    6.0000   11.0000   12.0000  111.2000
    2.0000    6.0000   10.0000   60.3900
    2.0000    3.0000   11.0000   87.1200
    1.0000    9.0000   20.0000  156.4800
```

Comment: Are you sure you should extract unique angles by sorting all first 3 columns?

Comment: @Argyll from the description, I figured it is exactly what he wants. One could also check for the last column, but it would enlarge the code.

Comment: 3 1 5 and 1 3 5 for example will be filtered out if you do that. But they are different angles. Checking the angle value won't help either.

Comment: @Argyll I cannot see, why it shouldn't work. I check the whole row, including IDs and angles. I am only sorting the first 3 columns, as the OP obviously wants rows with same angle and same IDs but in different order, filtered out.

Comment: As long as the vertex of the angle is different, it is a different angle. OP puts the vertex on the second column. So 3-1-5 and 1-3-5 are different angles. But sorting all 3 columns will make both 1-3-5 and eliminate one of them despite of not being identical.

Comment: @Argyll But that is not true, as long as the angle is different, nothing is filtered out. Please try out my code with the example rows you think wouldn't work. If they don't, share them and I will see. One downside of my answer is, that if the angles are different, despite the same vertices, it is not filtered out, but still sorted, what it probably shouldn't. But until now, thats not the case for the OPs data.

Comment: Are 3-1-5 and 1-3-5 stored separately under `@(x) { unique([sort( DATA(x,1:3), 2) DATA(x,4)], 'rows', 'stable' )}`?